# Profiler showing high percentage of time spent in node::ContextifyScript::New

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

When moving a project to run natively on a Raspberry Pi (Model B) with Node v6.6.0, I noticed significantly impacted performance (as might be expected).

I tried profiling the code to see where the possible improvements might be, and found that almost 40% of CPU time was spent in `node::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)`

What does this function do? Is it possible to find more info on how to optimize this script via the profiler?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this possibly had to do with memory usage - trying with some smaller inputs showed much better results and more sensible output from the profiler.

Comment: how were you able to determine that high CPU time in that function was caused by low memory?